# Multiply each column in a matrix by corresponding row in another and sum results in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

Lets say I have matrices `A = [1 2; 3 4], B = [4 3; 2 1]`. I want to multiply each column from matrix `A ([1; 3], [2; 4])` by the corresponding row in matrix `B ([4 3], [2 1])` and sum resulting matrices. I have came up with the following code:

```
C = zeros(size(A));
for i = 1 : size(A, 1)
  C = C + A(:, i) * B(i, :);
end
```

Could it be rewritten using some math trick or matlab function to get rid of the for loop?

I see there is unclarity in my question regarding the result I want. The result should exactly mimic provided Matlab code, therefore I seek one matrix which is given by the matrix summation of the intermediate matrices that are created by multiplying each column vector with corresponding row vector from both matrices. For this specific example, it would be given by

```
C = A(:, 1) * B(1, :) + A(:, 2) * B(2, :);
```

I am just looking for some generic, for-loop less version for any matrices of compatible dimensions.

Comment: I don't know matlab at all, but from my research, this should work:  `C = A * B` and then `result = sum(C(:))`.  Does that give the results you are looking for ?  Sources: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/matlab/matlab_matrix_multiplication.htm, https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/51252

Comment: Based on your update, @jodag's answer is correct.  `C = A * B` is equivalent to your matlab code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried out my suggestion in the comments, and it seems to work with this [octave tester](https://octave-online.net/):

Short form (only works in Octave):

```
A = [1 2; 3 4], B = [4 3; 2 1]
X = sum((A * B)(:))
```

Long form (Matlab):

```
A = [1 2; 3 4]
B = [4 3; 2 1]
C = A * B      % Stop here if you want the exact result from your Matlab code
x = sum(C(:))  % To get the sum of the resulting matrix
```

Sources:

1. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/matlab/matlab_matrix_multiplication.htm
2. https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/51252

**Update, based on your update:**

Output of `A * B`:

```
 8    5
20   13
```

Output of your code:

```
 8    5
20   13
```

Comment: The short form doesn't work in Matlab, only in Octav

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question. The question is asking for a matrix result, the result of your answer is a scalar.

Comment: In the question he states that he wants to get the "sum resulting matrices", so the last step is to do the sum of the product of the given martices.  Perhaps I'm mis-reading the original post ?

Comment: Maybe I'm blind but I don't see "sum of the product of the given martices" just the sum of the given matrices.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this in MATLAB, to get the sum.

`C=ones(1,2)*A*B*ones(2,1)`

The general form would be

`C=ones(1,size(A,1))*(A*B)*ones(size(B,2),1);`

**EDIT**

I see you updated your question for clarity.  The matrix product can be calculated directly

```
C = A*B;
```

as pointed out by [jodag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45473540/2254698).

This works provided you follow rules of linear algebra where inner dimensions of your matrices are the same (i.e. when number of columns in A match the number of rows in B; `size(A,2)==size(B,1)`).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that

```
C = zeros(size(A));
for i = 1 : size(A, 1)
  C = C + A(:, i) * B(i, :);
end
```

is equivalent to the matrix multiplication

```
C = A*B
```

for square matrices `A` and `B`.

Comment: Agreed.  This works for other dimensions as well, provided they follow the rules of linear algebra: inner dimensions of matrices A and B are the same (i.e. when number of columns in A match the number of rows in B; when `size(A,2)==size(B,1)`).